# Windows Server 2003: smtp and ftp services keep shutting down after a while

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, smtp, ftp

If I go into the IIS manager and start ftp and smtp, after about an hour or so they will have been shutdown. There is nothing in the event viewer to explain why they would shut down. IIS webserver continues to run with no problem.

I don't see any options in their configuration that would cause this.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking through the  log files? They can be found at *%windir%\system32\logfiles*

Comment: Yep, I just checked. Didn't see any clues in there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the Services under Administration and check to see if there were any unusual entries in the parameters section for them?  Are they set to restart upon failure?  Were there any new apps installed recently?

Comment: I just checked, but I didn't see any parameters that would do this. I did notice that they were set to manual start instead of automatic, I have changed to automatic to see if that helps.

But they have been stopping after I manually start, so I'm not sure that change will help.

Comment: did you install any new applications recently?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Process Monitor by Sysinternals. It can log process, registry, file system, and network activity for your smtp & ftp services.

With that info, you should be able to get a better idea of what's happening when the service processes exit, and go from there.